# AttributeError modul object has no attribute rindex | Django админка

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-admin

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

AttributeError at /admin/ 'module' object has no attribute 'rindex'
Проблема возникает только при попытке перейти на страницу админки 127.0.0.1:8000/admin/
Точно не могу сказать после чего появилась проблема, но заметил после того, как добавил новый модуль.

Trace:

```
    Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/

Django Version: 1.8.3
Python Version: 3.4.3
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'main',
 'photo',
 'news',
 'announce',
 'contact',
 'chief',
 'birthday',
 'bc')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.3-py3.4.egg\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.3-py3.4.egg\django\contrib\admin\sites.py" in wrapper
  254.                 return self.admin_view(view, cacheable)(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.3-py3.4.egg\django\utils\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  110.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.3-py3.4.egg\django\views\decorators\cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  57.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.3-py3.4.egg\django\contrib\admin\sites.py" in inner
  223.                 if request.path == reverse('admin:logout', current_app=self.name):
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.3-py3.4.egg\django\core\urlresolvers.py" in reverse
  550.                 app_list = resolver.app_dict[ns]
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.3-py3.4.egg\django\core\urlresolvers.py" in app_dict
  352.             self._populate()
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.3-py3.4.egg\django\core\urlresolvers.py" in _populate
  308.                     for name in pattern.reverse_dict:
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.3-py3.4.egg\django\core\urlresolvers.py" in reverse_dict
  338.             self._populate()
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.3-py3.4.egg\django\core\urlresolvers.py" in _populate
  326.                 lookups.appendlist(pattern.callback, (bits, p_pattern, pattern.default_args))
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.3-py3.4.egg\django\core\urlresolvers.py" in callback
  247.         self._callback = get_callable(self._callback_str)
File "C:\Python34\lib\functools.py" in wrapper
  448.                 result = user_function(*args, **kwds)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.3-py3.4.egg\django\core\urlresolvers.py" in get_callable
  96.     mod_name, func_name = get_mod_func(lookup_view)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.3-py3.4.egg\django\core\urlresolvers.py" in get_mod_func
  159.         dot = callback.rindex('.')

Exception Type: AttributeError at /admin/
Exception Value: 'module' object has no attribute 'rindex'
```

url сайта:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns, static
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from khm.settings import *
from main.views import *


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^photo/', include("photo.urls")),
    url(r'^news/', include("news.urls")),
    url(r'^announce/', include("announce.urls")),
    url(r'^contact/', include("contact.urls")),
    url(r'^chief/', include("chief.urls")),
    url(r'^birthday/', include("birthday.urls")),
    url(r'^bc/', include("bc.urls")),
]

urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
urlpatterns += url(r'^', include("main.urls")),
```

url приложения:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from birthday.views import *

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', bthd, name="bthd"),
]
```

model приложения:

```
from django.db import models

class Birthday(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256, verbose_name="ФИО", null=True, blank=True)
    dob = models.DateField()
    pn = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="Порядковый номер", null=True, blank=True)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='birthday/photo',verbose_name="Фото",
                                    blank=False, null=False, default='birthday/photo/photo.jpg')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta():
        db_table = "Дни рождения"
        verbose_name = "Дни рождения"
```

Админка приложения:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from birthday.models import *
from birthday.views import *

class Birthday_admin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ('name', 'dob', 'pn', 'photo',)
    ordering = ('-dob',)
    list_display = ('name', 'dob')

admin.site.register(Birthday, Birthday_admin)
```

settings:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'main',
    'photo',
    'news',
    'announce',
    'contact',
    'chief',
    'birthday',
    'bc',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'khm.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': ['C:/Python34/khm/main/template',
                 'C:/Python34/khm/photo/template',
                 'C:/Python34/khm/announce/template',
                 'C:/Python34/khm/news/template',
                 'C:/Python34/khm/contact/template',
                 'C:/Python34/khm/chief/template',
                 'C:/Python34/khm/birthday/template',
                 'C:/Python34/khm/bc/template',
                 ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'django.template.context_processors.media',
                'django.core.context_processors.media',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'khm.wsgi.application'



DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}



LANGUAGE_CODE = 'ru-ru'

TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Moscow'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True



STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),)

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'uploads')
MEDIA_URL = '/uploads/'

LOGIN_URL = "login"
LOGOUT_URL = "logout"
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = "/"
LOGOUT_URL_REDIRECT_URL = "/"

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'main.AuthUser'
```

birthday.views:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, render_to_response, redirect
from django.template import RequestContext
from birthday.models import *
from datetime import date

#today = date.today()

def bthd(request):
    args = {}
    return render_to_response("bd.html", args, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    """
    args['birthdays'] = Birthday.objects.order_by('-dob')
    if Birthday.objects.get(dob=today):
        args['bd_today'] = Birthday.objects.get(dob=today)
        args['birthdays'] = Birthday.objects.order_by('-dob')
        return render_to_response("bd.html", args, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    else:
        args['birthdays'] = Birthday.objects.order_by('-dob')
        return render_to_response("bd.html", args, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    """
```

Comment: в `urls` надо `views.bthd` вместо `bthd`

Comment: @super16 не помогло (пришлось переделать impor, но не суть). Методология, которой я руководствуюсь от приложения к приложению идентична. Т.е. все делаю одинаково и поэтому не могу понять в чем проблема.
На саму страницу(birthday) переход совершается, проблема возникает при переходе на админку